# Android/Java: How to use Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library?

Tags: java, android, proxy, tor, socks

I will connect to a server in an Android app with tor but without using orbot.
I found this Library: https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library

I added

```
    compile 'com.github.jehy:Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library:0.0.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'
```

to my build.gradle (Module: app) and

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}

Next I added in my Fragment in the onCreateView

```
    int totalSecondsPerTorStartup = 4 * 60;
    int totalTriesPerTorStartup = 5;
    try {
        boolean ok = onionProxyManager.startWithRepeat(totalSecondsPerTorStartup, totalTriesPerTorStartup);
        if (!ok)
            Log.e("TorTest", "Couldn't start Tor!");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'onionProxyManager'`. I followed the instructions on Github...

If I change `onionProxyManager` to `OnionProxyManager` I can import `com.msopentech.thali.toronionproxy.OnionProxyManager` but I get than an error on `startWithRepeat`.

So please help me if you can. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this library https://github.com/PanagiotisDrakatos/T0rlib4Android

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalSecondsPerTorStartup = 4 * 60;
int totalTriesPerTorStartup = 5;
String fileStorageLocation = "torfiles";
OnionProxyManager onionProxyManager =
        new AndroidOnionProxyManager(getActivity(), fileStorageLocation);
    public void start(){
// Start the Tor Onion Proxy
try {
  boolean ok = onionProxyManager.startWithRepeat(totalSecondsPerTorStartup, totalTriesPerTorStartup);
// Now the socket is open but note that it can take some time before the Tor network has everything
// connected and connection requests can fail for spurious reasons (especially when connecting to
// hidden services) so have lots of retry logic.
  if (!ok)
    // Log.e("TorTest", "Couldn't start Tor!");
    return;
  }
  catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You copied that from the README.md. I already tested this. It does not work!

Comment: The readme file on that github page is missing the [code]OnionProxyManager onionProxyManager = new AndroidOnionProxyManager(this.getApplicationContext(), fileStorageLocation);[/code] which is from the thailproject page and does indeed bootstrap. If you call onionProxyManager.isBootstrapped(); you can get the status. Hope this helps

Comment: I get `Cannot resolve symbol onionProxyManager and totalTriesPerTorStartup and totalSecondsPerTorStartup`

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing a lot of issues getting that library to work. It didn't had clear documentation. So, I created a sample app to show how that library can be used, and had sent a pull request to that repository. PR was accpeted and it is now available in that repository. You can check out the sample app here: https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library/tree/master/SampleTorProxyApp

It is not as simple as pasting the given example code. First, read the updated [README](https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library/blob/master/README.md). If you are not able to understand it, then head over to see how it is implemented in the sample app. See how you should use it in your MainActivity [here](https://github.com/NandanDesai/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library/blob/master/SampleTorProxyApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/nandan/sampletorproxyapp/MainActivity.java). You will need to create your own custom ConnectionSocketFactory and SSLConnectionSocketFactory classes if you wish to use it with HttpClient to send/receive data from/to a server through Tor (as shown [here](https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library/tree/master/SampleTorProxyApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/nandan/sampletorproxyapp).)